# How to use ocl::KnearestNeigbhour with an array of images

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, knn

I am trying to perform KNN to classify an image using OpenCV and OpenCL. The module ocl in OpenCV provides just that with the class ocl::KnearestNeigbhour. However, I deal with image that might be rather large. This causes the process to be aborded since Windows requires that a kernel being on the gpu responsible for the screen display does not take more than 2 seconds (see WDDM TDR).

To avoid this problem, I split up the image in a series of smaller images and I classify them iterally using a for loop. When using the non gpu version CvKNearest class, it works like a charm. Unfortunately, when I am using the ocl::KnearestNeighbour class, then the result from the first image is repeted over and over for all other images in the series.

Here is the code I am using :

```
cv::Mat mResult(mImgLab.rows, mImgLab.cols, CV_32FC1);

cv::ocl::KNearestNeighbour knn;
knn.train(mtrainData, mlabels);

for (int i = 0; i * ROW_NUMBER < mImgLab.rows; i++)
{
    int iStart = i * ROW_NUMBER;
    int iStop = std::min(mImgLab.rows, iStart + ROW_NUMBER);
    int iSpan = iStop - iStart;

    int iRows = iSpan * mImgLab.cols;

    cv::ocl::oclMat mOclSample(mImgLab.rowRange(iStart, iStop).reshape(1, iRows));
    cv::ocl::oclMat mOclKnn(iRows, 1, CV_32FC1);
    knn.find_nearest(mOclSample, K, mOclKnn);
    cv::Mat mKnn = mOclKnn;

    mKnn = mKnn.reshape(0, iSpan);

    mKnn.copyTo(mResult.rowRange(iStart, iStop));
}
```

So my question is, how can I split an image so my kernels on the GPU are not too big?

Comment: I did it to test the function at first. However, the process might take a while, and the computer screen completely freezes which is not really convinient for the users.

Comment: I'm guessing `knn.find_nearest(mOclSample, K, mOclKnn);` modifies the state of the `kNearestNeighbour` instance, which is why the results get repeated. There seems to be a `clear()` function available for this class, maybe this is what you need to do? Otherwise, maybe create a copy of `knn` after it has been trained or something and reuse it at each loop iteration?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the answer, unfortunatly this didn't solve the problem. What i had tried to do was to instantiate and train `kNearestNeighbhour` inside the loop. Following your suggestion I even added the clear method to really make sure that the object was cleared, but nothing is working. Is it possible there are some thread running even after the call? Isn't there some kind of syncing mechanism at the end of the function? Thanks again for your help guys.